# Why low volume of atom indicates low attraction forces between atoms which could determine if a gas is ideal or not?

Tags: ideal-gas

I have the following question about ideal gas.

> A helium atom has a volume of 4.9 x 10^-31 m^3. Explain with the reference to the kinetic model, why this sample of helium can be assumed to be ideal (The volume of the helium gas is about 3.2 x 10^6)

The reason turns to be that

> the volume of each atom is too small (negigible) compared to the
> volume of the whole gas which means there are almost no attractive forces between particles which means all internal energy is kinetic.

I understand that in ideal gas, we can ignore the volume taken up by the imaginary ideal gas molecules.

But just wonder why low volumes of atom indicates low attraction between atoms and almost no bonds between molecules for it to break?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The "reason" doesn't make sense; whether atoms are small compared to a macroscale sample has no bearing on the strength of the attractive forces between them. Consider finding a better teaching resource.

Answer (score 0):

One of the assumptions of the kinetic model is that the total volume occupied by the individual atoms is negligible to the volume occupied by the gas as a whole. This means the distance between atoms is large compared to the atom size so that any distance-dependant interatomic forces have a negligible effect. So the only change in momentum of the atoms occurs during collisions which are treated as perfectly elastic.